# How to change the value of common entries between two lists to zero (or anything else) in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

Let's say I have two lists

```
listA = ['a', 'b' , 'q' , 'y' , 'r']
listB = ['p', 'y' , 't' , 'h', 'a' , 'w', 'n']
```

Then I want to compare both `listA` and `listB` with each other and
Then update `listA` as

```
listA = [0 , 'b' , 'q' , 0 , 'r']
```

the replaced value could be `0` or `'0'` or `any other value of my choosing`.

I am totally new to programming by the way.

But what I have tried is

```
if any(x in listA for x in listB):
    listA[x] = 0
```

but the result i am getting is

```
listA = [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ]
```

or first n items of `listA` becomes `0` where `n = length of listB`

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Dr. Tree

---

Tried:

```
if any(x in listA for x in listB):
    listA[x] = 0
```

Expecting:

```
listA = [0,'b','q',0,'r']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to recreate the list.

```py
listA = [0 if x in listB else x for x in listA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the best answer, but some useful info for anyone confused as to why the OP does not work.

Couple of things to remember here:

1. `listA[x] = 0` is a single assignment operation. If you want to be able to replace a finite amount of list elements with some value, then you will need the same number of assignment operations. Put another way, each element to be replaced needs to be reassigned.
2. `listA[x]` is a the reference to the value from `listA` at index `x`, where `x` is a variable (therefore, the index is determined by the value of `x`). This is easily confused with the index of the element in `listA` that you want to replace. Put another way, if you want to replace the 1st (at index `0`) element of `listA`, that has a previous value of say `5`, you reassign `listA[0]`, not `listA[5]`.

Here is a workable solution (with comments) for what you want:

```
listA = ['a', 'b' , 'q' , 'y' , 'r']
listB = ['p', 'y' , 't' , 'h', 'a' , 'w', 'n']

# Loop over every element from listB
for elB in listB:
    # For each one, loop over every element in listA (for comparison).
    # This uses "enumeration" so we have the index of each element
    # in `i` for when we need to do any re-assignment.
    for i, elA in enumerate(listA):
        # If the element from listB is a member of listA, replace
        # the element from listA with `0`.
        if elA == elB:
            listA[i] = 0

print(listA)  # [0, 'b', 'q', 0, 'r']
```

There are some more elegant ways to do this in Python, but this "exploded" view gives you a good understanding of what is going on.

Some cases to consider:

- Are any of these elements duplicated? In which lists?
- Could the elements being replaced have the same value as the one with which you are replacing?
  ...and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed review of the problem. I'm afraid I have to take my fair share of time to understand the details explained in your post. And, It is true that I am not comparing  just two lists. My actual program is to take any string input from the user, boil it down to a list of lowercase alphabets and then compare them with 8 lists where different alphabets are grouped together graded from 1 to 8  but in no particular order, using them as reference, the list would be converted into a string of numbers. continued due to character limitations.

Comment: Then further the string of numbers thus obtained would be summed until it is reduced to to a single digit and then use that digit to find the root character if it is between 1 and 8. In the case of 9, the index of the first occurrence of 'i' is obtained and used a root digit else, it will be substituted with a character that is at the circular distance equivalent to 9 in the group that i belongs to and then its index is used as the root digit and so on until a character is obtained.